# Can AdjustTokenPrivileges elevate the privilege as Administrator?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

Programs under windows need administrator privilege must get user's permission when they start. And they can also run with administrator privilege by right click the EXE and select "Run as Administrator". But, before the EXE start, a message box will show up. It's really disgusting.

Now I want my application to run as the Administrator, and I don't want the popup message box when user click the EXE file.

Now I wonder whether the AdjustTokenPrivileges function can help me achieve this.

Any one can help me?

Comment: What's your use case?  In other words, what's special about your application that means it needs to run as administrator without getting the user's permission to do so?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're getting confused between rights and privileges. At least from the viewpoint of the Windows API, the two are entirely different (though they're otherwise treated as synonymous a great deal of the time, at least when dealing with "what you can do on Windows").

What you're really looking for is the ability to elevate *rights*. Short of some defect in the security model of the system, you shouldn't be able to do this. To get administrative rights, the intent is that the code should have to run under an administrative account -- either by the user initially logging in as an administrator, or else by them entering the credentials at run time as you've seen.

Privileges (which are what `AdjustTokenPrivileges` actually manipulates) are things you have the *right* to do, but still aren't allowed to do without specifically *enabling* that privilege. For example, let's assume you start out logged in as an administrator. That gives you the *right* to adjust the system clock -- but adjusting the system clock is something normal programs almost never have a reason to do, so they added an extra step, before you can do it -- you need to enable the `SE_SYSTEMTIME` privilege before you can make use of that right.

If you're logged in under an account that doesn't have the *right* to change the system time, you simply can't do it. If you're logged into an account that *can* change it, you have to enable the privilege first before you can do it.

Bottom line: `AdjustTokenPrivileges` won't accomplish what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a way, which allows you to change security credentials for the thread by calling `LogonUser` API function. It returns handle to a token which could be used in `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` and `CreateProcessAsUser` calls. This technique is called impersonalization.

Howewer, I think you are trying to achieve a different thing - to run a process with elevated administrative rights without UAC user notification. You could either disable UAC completely in msconfig utility, which is a pretty bad solution, or leave your program as it is, because to be quite frank, user has a right to know, when your program is running with superuser privileges, and disabling this notifications should be his decision.