# TerminateProcess not working for specific processes

Tags: c++, winapi, process

I need to terminate some processes before my program can run, but whenever I run `TerminateProcess()`, `GetLastError()` returns 5. What I know so far is that this means that access is denied, I also know that to elevate my rights i need to use `AdjustTokenPrivileges()`, based on Rango's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095581) and Microsoft's documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/sacl-access-right).

What i don't know is why it wont work. Based on what I've read, the following should work:

```cpp
BOOL TerminateMyProcess(DWORD dwProcessId, UINT uExitCode)
{
    DWORD dwDesiredAccess = PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS;
    //DWORD dwDesiredAccess = ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY;
    BOOL  bInheritHandle = FALSE;
    HANDLE hProcess = NULL;

    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp = { 0 };
    LUID luid;

    LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_SECURITY_NAME, &luid);

    tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

    AdjustTokenPrivileges(hProcess, FALSE, &tp, 0, NULL, NULL);

    hProcess = OpenProcess(dwDesiredAccess, bInheritHandle, dwProcessId);
    BOOL result = TerminateProcess(hProcess, uExitCode);

    CloseHandle(hProcess);

    return result;
}
```

As you can tell from the above, I am not sure which `dwDesiredAccess` I am supposed to use. `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` lets me terminate other simple processes, such as chrome.exe or notepad.exe, but not what i need to terminate. `ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY` is whats' said to be used by microsoft, but then i cannot terminate any process at all.

Also, is this even close to what i need to do, if not can you please point me in the right direction.

**UPDATE:** Added `UpdatePrivilege()` function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095581), and called it before calling `OpenProcess()` function, still no bite.

**UPDATE 2:** The process I need to terminate is the "afwServ.exe" process, i.e. Avast's firewall. I need to do this so that my firewall is the *sole* firewall used by Windows. This a requirement of my project.

Comment: you need use `PROCESS_TERMINATE` instead `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS`. at second - in your code you not check any result. are you sure that you got access denied from `TerminateProcess` but not from `OpenProcess` ?

Comment: `PROCESS_TERMINATE ` behaves the same as `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS`, and `GetLastError()` returns 6 after `OpenProcess()`. `GetLastError()` also returns 6 after `TerminateProcess()` runs properly, i.e. terminating stuff like notepad.exe, so i don't think that's the issue. The issue, i think, lies in `TerminatProcess()` and my implementation of it.

Comment: 6 -- this is invalid handle. *after TerminateProcess() runs properly* - no sense call `GetLastError()`. begin from check any function call result/error

Comment: I get 6 when i call `AdjustTokenPrivileges()`. Do you think this is the issue?

Comment: of course this is error from your side `AdjustTokenPrivileges` require valid handle to token, when you pass 0 here

Comment: I have added the function word for word from the other question i linked, and ran that before calling `OpenProcess()`. No more error code:6. But i still get error code:5 after running `TerminateProcess()`

Comment: if you really open process with `PROCESS_TERMINATE` - you must not got access denied from call `TerminateProcess`, only if some driver not protect it. but you still not fix your code in question

Comment: *"I need to terminate some processes before my program can run"* - That sounds a lot like you should either fix your program, or revisit your system design.

Comment: In short, i am making a firewall, and to avoid conflicts with other firewalls, i need to disable, terminate, or overrule all other firewalls. I have done so for Windows Firewall, but i need to do this for other firewalls. The service i need to terminate is the afwServ.exe process, i.e. the firewall used by avast. So i was wondering how I could terminate the process before starting mine.

Comment: No. That's not what to do. Ask the user to disable the other firewalls. It has to be their choice. Otherwise your software is malware.

Answer (score -1):

I think you misunderstood the difference between right and privileges, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019410/can-adjusttokenprivileges-elevate-the-privilege-as-administrator/12019470#12019470) explains it.

In this case, your current user may not have permission to terminate the specified process. You may first need to use [`LogonUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonusera) and use administrator identity to simulate the process context.

What you want to terminate is a service, you can try using [`ControlService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-controlservice) with `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP` to stop the services. But you also need to switch to the user with permission first.

Comment: So using this I can take the name of the process/exe and 'logon' as administrator, open a process handle and terminate it, or do i have to open a service handle and stop the service from there? 
What if i come across a situation where there is a third party firewall installed that solely runs as as process, not as a service. In this scenario, can i run both service and process handling? So it can work with both situations.

Comment: if it run as a process, then you could certainly terminate it in the same user which started it.(Administrtor as well) And if it run as a service, then the default own is local system, which cannot be terminated by a normal user, but administrtors are able to.